# Как обходить склик рекламы Adwords и Яндекс

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, фильтр

Вообщем-то спустя месяц работы сайта заказчика
Конкуренты начали скликивать рекламу и по итогу большие расходы и 0 профита
Пытался решить вопрос сбором айпа и последующего бана 
Но есть ли возможность сделать свой фильтр ботов на js
Дайте идей ребят,буду благодарен

Comment: Если делают клики пользователи вручную, а не скриптом - никак не сможете их отловить. Терпите :)

Comment: А если скриптом, как таких ботов блочить?

Comment: Зависит от скрипта. Можно анализировать время клика, поведение мышки (боты обычно не водят мышкой по экрану, перед кликом). Но, на каждую защиту найдется контрмера. Весь вопрос - в затраченном усилии и времени.

Comment: Ну это, конечно ,все понятно
Вопрос остается в том как им закрывать доступ 
Тип фильтрация ип не вижу смысла
Они же динамические 
А так в голову ничего не приходит

Comment: А откуда предположение, что это именно конкуренты? А не просто пользователи, которые к вам пришли и не нашли у вас на сайте ничего интересного?